# ajax request throwing error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement a static `javascript` / `jQuery` script for testing my `ajax` functions. This would be for instance somewhere in my home directory and would contain a bunch of `ajax` requests to my `localhost`:

```
function getSomethingAjax(){
    $.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/getSomething',{} , function(json){    
        getSomethingCallback(json);
    }, "json");
}
```

My Firebug gives my an error like this:
[firebug screenshot http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/4934/tinygrabscreenshot06061.png](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/4934/tinygrabscreenshot06061.png)
But if I open the page manually (just type in browser: 127.0.0.1:8888/getSomething) I get the matching return. What is the difference between accessing the url? I the `ajax` request waiting for a specific return value?

Comment: Try removing the absolute url to getSomething and only use /getSomething . Anyway cross-domain requests are not allowed. And also I don't think it's a good idea to name your variable "json" as it may be a restricted keyword. That variable is usualy called "data"

Comment: File extension? `getSomething.php` or `getSomething.asp`.

Comment: it's a call to php's codeigniter it's actually something like 127.0.0.1:8888/ci/app/index.php/getSomething

Comment: So there is no way to do a cross domain ajax call? I wan't to do the testing from home desk without uploading the test.js to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page making the Ajax request and page requested must be in the same domain.

The browser will block any ajax request that violates this.

Just a suggestion:
I would suggest to use a server side language to do the tests. This will allow you to make call to the application without having to keep the test scripts in the same domain.

Comment: how would an application call from a foreign domain look like?

Comment: If you are using Java you can do that with HttpURLConnection. curl in PHP.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the problem - I tried the first approach from this [article](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/) - getting no error by trying his [url](http://twitter.com/users/usejquery.json?callback=?) but trying my url throws the same error as before

Comment: Its a JSONP request a work around for cross-domain calls. If you can modify your application to support that then you can also use it.

Comment: so I managed to do that! Thanks for the hint, finally I used the method in this [article](http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/07/09/how-to-access-cross-domain-data-with-ajax-using-jsonp-jquery-and-php/) and got it working now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your returning address doesn't match yours.
If you send a request using 127.0.0.1 then the server returns localhost it will fail. Try using localhost instead of the IP?